# express nodejs post req.body undefined

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, post

I am working on a board with express 2.11.3 and node v0.12.7 running on it.

There is a server in node.js and I would like to retrieve data from a POST form. For the moment, "req.body.quota1" is returning undefined. Below is my code.

"req.path" and "req.ip" return values. req.body returns [Object object] and req.body.quota1 returns undefined.

Curl command line seems to work with the app `curl -d "quota1=2" -X POST http://ip:8080/submitParams`. I mean, that req.body.quota1 returns 2.

What is stopping my code from retrieving data from the post form ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Best regards,

JG2

**index.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var  express = require('express')
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: false 
}))
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'text/html'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets')));

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
 defaultLayout: 'layout',
 extname: '.hbs',
 layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname),
 partialsDir: path.join(__dirname)
}))

app.set('view engine', '.hbs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname))

var server = app.listen(8080);
require('./user').init(app);
```

**./user/init.js**

```
function initUser(app) {
  app.get('/', renderWelcome);
  app.post('/submitParams',submitParams);
}

function submitParams(req,res)                            
{                                                       
  console.log("req.ip: " + req.ip);
  console.log(req.path);
  console.log("req.body: " + req.body);  
  console.log("req.body.quota1: " + req.body.quota1);  
  

res.render('user/welcome',{                           
  ...                           
  })                                                                                                                                                      
}                 

module.exports = initUser
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/submitParams" method="post" style="width:200px;">
  <label for="quota1">Quota 1</label>
  <input name="quota1" type="text" value={{quota1}}>
  <button type="submit">Submit new quotas</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Check to see what content-type and data is actually sent in the request.

Comment: `value={{quota1}}` isn't typical HTML. It suggests you are using JSX which makes it likely you have some client-side JS interfering with the request.

Comment: `console.log("req.body: " + req.body);` — Don't cast the body to a string, it doesn't tell you what it actually contains. `log` accepts multiple arguments: `console.log("req.body", req.body)`.

Comment: **Response Header**
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8
Content-Length: 1718. 
**Request Headers**
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0. Dpes this mean no data is being sent in the request?

Comment: value={{quota1}} is because I am using Express handlebars. I removed it to check if that is the problem, it didn't change anything

Comment: content-length: 0 does mean that there is no data, but there should be because the input has a name.

Comment: I'll look into it... is it a problem that response/request headers have different content-types?

Comment: No. It's perfectly normal to submit form data and get an HTML document back.

Comment: So far still no luck finding why content-length: 0... Do you have an idea why/tips where I should look?

Comment: Found the problem! I hadn't pasted all the html code here, and saw that I actually had a different button calling /submitParams. So I guess the button was overriding the form. Silly me. Thank you very much for your help.